# Simple socket.io example not work

Tags: node.js, socket.io

This is server file

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(7000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("### new connection ###");
});
```

This is for client

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect('http://address.net:7000');
    console.log(socket);
});
```

Server starts correct without any errors.
I copied from node_modules and attach to my site < head > section file "socket.io.min.js" file for client from dist folder.

And in output of server isn't any ### new connection ### when I run my site.
Why?

Comment: I would start by checking that $j is defined and that address.net is the correct address.

Comment: check the source of the socket.io.js-file. in my case i run my server locally on port 8080. i get the script with 
`<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

Comment: i moved this file tu my public_html and attach it like I don't know, like jQuery. I moved it because i dont create http server in node, don't need it.

Comment: How are you loading the page containing your client code? If it's by a `file://` URL, it's unlikely to work due to security mechanisms.

Comment: it is on my server that I bought. So I load page just by my domain and http protocol.

Comment: This is what I get from browser console:
SocketNamespace (this is console.log(socket) in client file)
Failed to load resource http://address.net:7000/socket.io/1/?t=1346164524648

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem resolved. It was about wrong server address in socket.io connection function.